# What css must I apply to get rid of this useless spacing?

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a navbar that has some items, 4 of them to the left and one that must always be in the right. The thing is when I introduced the last one to the left, they got one word on top of the other and it looks awful. And one more thing is that when I change the resolution of the monitor, the item that's always on the right moves to the left almost touching the middle.

Some additional info would be that this is part of a project consisting in a web platform for colleges. It is mainly created with SpringBoot and its libraries, fully Java written in backend. Nonetheless, the frontend is mostly HTML, some CSS when I need to make it not look ugly and Javascript in case of animatios of effects. Also not to mention Thymeleaf framework so I can communicate with the backend properly.

I tried many things but I have no idea how to make them look nice. Someone willing to help me on this stylish matter?
I will add two pictures:

- this one is when I have my browser put on the 24inch screen [image]
- this one is when I have my browser put on the 15.6inch screen of the laptop [image]

And the code below is from the page:

```css
#personal-page {
  padding-left: 780px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#admin-page {
  padding-left: 730px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#assistant-page {
  padding-left: 700px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <nav class="fixed-top navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://curs.upb.ro/">
      <span class="fa fa-university"></span> E-Learning Platform
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="navi">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Homepage<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/menu">Menu Page</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/admin/students">Students List</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/admin/camine">Camine Page</a>
        </li>

        <div th:switch="${isDevAcc}">
          <li th:case="'true'" class="nav-item">
            <div th:switch="${loggedUsername}">
              <a th:case="'iancu'" id="admin-page" class="nav-link fas fa-code" aria-current="page" href="/admin/devAdminPage">
                <span> Dev Account :: ADMIN </span>
              </a>
              <a th:case="'lixi'" id="assistant-page" class="nav-link fas fa-code" aria-current="page" href="/admin/devAdminPage">
                <span> Dev Account :: ASISTENT </span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li th:case="'false'" class="nav-item" id="personal-page">
            <a class="nav-link fas fa-user-secret" aria-current="page" href="#" th:text="${loggedUsername}"></a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please note that you have an Invalid HTMl markup. The `head` element is for META data not content to be displayed. What you proberly want is a `<header>` which has to be part of the `body` element. Also a `div` is not allowed to be a direct child of an `ul` element.

Comment: I understand @tacoshy, but that doen't solve my issue at all. I will modify from head to header so it can be properly be written in HTML. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It would be better to understand if you could add all of your CSS

Comment: Are you using any CSS framwork/library

Comment: The provided code doesn't reproduce what's shown in the image. Please create [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexbox` to align your navbar horizontally: `nav ul { display: flex; }`

Then you also can use the `:last-child` selector to apply `margin-left: auto;` which will push the last item to the right: `nav ul li:last-child { margin-left: auto; }`. `margin: auto;` within a `flex-container` will consume all remaining space.

```css
nav ul {  
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* For styling purpose only */

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>E-Learning Plattform</li>
    <li>Homepage</li>
    <li>Menu Page</li>
    <li>Students List</li>
    <li>Camine Page</li>
    <li>Admin</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```